# Event Handling in Visual Basic using a graphical interface

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, model-view-controller, event-handling

At the moment I'm introducing myself into the language Visual Basic, using the Visual Studio 2010 as an IDE.

I want to create a graphical application and therefore using the MVC pattern to implement it. But I wonder slightly about the Eventhandling. Actually I want the GUI to raise events that can be handled by the controller. But I cannot handle the events of the GUI in other classes, only in the class itself. So I defined some files implementing partially the GUI class, handling the events and call the controller. But according to my understanding of the MVC pattern the controller should not be called by the GUI class - how I understand it, it has to be vice-versa so the GUI raises an event, the controller handles this event and perhaps shows something else on the GUI.

I tried to instantiate the GUI class in the controller and to use the instance to handle the events but this way seems to be wrong because I've no access on the events the instance raises.

In general I hope that anyone can explain me the realization of MVC in Visual Basic more proper than I did it myself.

Comment: `But I cannot handle the events of the GUI in other classes` - you [surely can](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka(v=vs.100).aspx). Anyone can subscribe to a public event of a class, and `System.Windows.Form` is a class with public events.

Comment: Can you show us some code so that we can get an idea of what you mean, please?  Preferably your event declarations and also the handlers in your controller class.

Comment: GSerg, I am so sorry. I have not seen the most important page about event handling. Thank you so much. Now i know how to implement it properly.